# How to replace some class names with others and to show this changes specially?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, onload, addclass, removeclass

`<ul>` has many `<li>` items which some part of them are `highlighted` and others are `simple`:

```
<ul class="news">
      <li class="highlighted">Item 1</li>
      <li class="highlighted">Item 2</li>
      <li class="simple">Item 3</li>
      <li class="highlighted">Item 4</li>
      <li class="simple">Item 5</li>
      <li class="simple">Item 6</li>
      <li class="highlighted">Item 7</li>
      <li class="simple">Item 8</li>
      //...etc..
</ul>
```

I need when this page load, to set all `highlighted` items to `simple`.

***If its possible to show changed items specially for striking.** Like `fadeOut()` or replace classes 2 times, at end, set all items to `simple` class.*

I tried like this, but not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.news').onload(function () {
        $(this).find(".highlighted").each(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
            }, 4500);
            $(this).addClass("simple");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What the `onload` should do? remove it!

Comment: You don't need the `class='simple'` as it's you "default" state. Consider that no class is the same as your actual 'simple'. And it'll improve the readability of your code.

Comment: That is my default state.

Comment: @Mores, that is his point exactly...

Comment: @EdouardLopez - You're assuming that `simple` doesn't add some other formatting. Though if there is a `li.simple` class in the stylesheet it would be neater to use `ul.news li` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will wait 4.5s then removed the `highlighted` class from all elements within the `news` element and replace it with `simple`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.news > .highlighted').toggleClass('highlighted simple');
        }, 4500);
       });       
    });
</script>
```

If you want them done one at a time, 4.5s apart that would look like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.news > .highlighted').each(function(i) {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                 $self.toggleClass('highlighted simple');
            }, (i + 1) * 4500);
        });      
    });
</script>
```

If you want a fade out effect then fade in with a different look that might look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.news > .highlighted').each(function(i) {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                 $self.fadeOut(function() {
                      $self.toggleClass('highlighted simple')
                           .fadeIn();
                 });
            }, (i + 1) * 4500);
        });      
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cache `this`, get rid of `onload`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.news').find(".highlighted").each(function () {
        var $that = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $that.removeClass('highlighted');
        }, 4500);
        $that.addClass("simple");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2j44/)

Answer (score 1):

> *" or replace classes 2 times, at end, set all items to simple class."*

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $lisToChange = $("ul.news li.highlighted");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       setTimeout(function() {
           $lisToChange.toggleClass('highlighted simple');
       }, i * 500 + 500);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ex6tw/1

That is, get a reference to just the elements that will need to change (`$lisToChange` in my code) and then toggle the classes on just those elements. To draw attention to the change by doing it several times just use `setTimeout()` in a loop.